# Create new record with default values LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

how to navigate to new record create a page with some default values as we do in a lightning `$A.get("e.force:createRecord")` in LWC

I have tried the below code, but not working:

```
           this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
                type: 'standard__objectPage',
                attributes: {
                    objectApiName: 'Corrective_Action__c',
                    defaultFieldValues: {
                        "Key_Action__c" : this.principlerecid
                    },
                    recordTypeId : this.correctiveActionId,
                    actionName: 'new'
                }
            },true);
```

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/375009/ive-built-an-object-agnostic-lwc-invoked-from-a-quick-action-that-prepopulates

Comment: Here is a complete solution: [Navigate to new record creation modal with pre-populated values.](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/375009/ive-built-an-object-agnostic-lwc-invoked-from-a-quick-action-that-prepopulates)

Answer (score 9):

This is a kind of limitation in Lightning web Component. [Setting default values isn't yet supported, and planned for an upcoming release.](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/issues/66)

I have created one idea on this:- [Allow setting pre-default values in record form by navigation service in LWC](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000CYGkQAO)

You can upvote this. For time being continue using force:createrecord in your aura Component.

### Update

In spring 20, this feature has been delivered by Salesforce.

See this [link](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_lc_navigate_to_record_dfv.htm). According to it, We can do this as follow:-

```
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__objectPage',
            attributes: {
                objectApiName: 'Account',
                actionName: 'new'                
            },
            state : {
                nooverride: '1',
                defaultFieldValues:"Name=Salesforce,AccountNumber=A1,AnnualRevenue=37000,Phone=7055617159"
            }
});
```

Comment: But how to create a record that does not use hard coded values, but fields from the currently displayed object? I guess we need more JS code for that?

Answer (score 4):

The ability to navigate to a new record with default values has been added to LEX, and ready for use in both Aura and LWC components as of Spring 20, as specified in the release [notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_lc_navigate_to_record_dfv.htm).

There is a good example that can be found in Aura documentation right now, but the LWC documentation is still missing at this point, because although referenced in [the docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-pageReferenceUtils/documentation), the link is currently broken. Hopefully this will be addressed soon.

For now, there is a [recipe](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/tree/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/navToNewRecordWithDefaults) in the `lwc-recipes` sample app. Here is the JS code. Note use of `lightning/pageReferenceUtils` to encode the default values:

```js
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
import { encodeDefaultFieldValues } from 'lightning/pageReferenceUtils';

export default class NavToNewRecord extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    // below, we take an object and encode it to work with navigation
    navigateToNewContactWithDefaults() {
        const defaultValues = encodeDefaultFieldValues({
            FirstName: 'Morag',
            LastName: 'de Fault',
            LeadSource: 'Other'
        });

        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__objectPage',
            attributes: {
                objectApiName: 'Contact',
                actionName: 'new'
            },
            state: {
                defaultFieldValues: defaultValues // and here we set defaults as a nav parameter
            }
        });
    }
}
```

One note, `sfdx-lwc-jest` currently has not implemented the required package `lightning/pageReferenceUtils`, so you will not be able to test without mocking this package. An [issue](https://github.com/salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest/issues/127) has been raised in that repo. For now, the recipes app has left a commented-out-but-most-likely-working [test](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/navToNewRecordWithDefaults/__tests__/navToNewRecordWithDefaults.test.js) in place.

Answer (score 1):

To construct a custom button or link that launches a new record with prepopulated field values, use this sample formula:

```
/lightning/o/Account/new?defaultFieldValues=
    Name={!URLENCODE(Account.Name)},
    OwnerId={!Account.OwnerId},
    AccountNumber={!Account.AccountNumber},
    NumberOfEmployees=35000,
    CustomCheckbox__c={!IF(Account.SomeCheckbox__c, true, false)}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is now supported in spring 20. Here is a code sample for you.

```
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__objectPage',
            attributes: {
                objectApiName: 'Account',
                actionName: 'new'                
            },
            state : {
                nooverride: '1',
                defaultFieldValues:"Name=Tushar Sharma,AccountNumber=55555,NumberOfEmployees=35000,Phone=9988776655,Site=https://newstechnologystuff.com/"
            }
        });
```

We can use `state` parameter with `defaultFieldValues` to provide default values.

You can find complete code with sample component here: [Default Field Values using Lightning Web Components](https://newstechnologystuff.com/2020/01/20/default-field-values-using-lightning-web-components/)

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce adding support for it in [Spring'20](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_lc_navigate_to_record_dfv.htm)